# Adding icons in DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, icons

Is there a way to put icons for each row in a DataGrid in c #?

Comment: What kind of DataGrid? WinForms? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

On WinForms, you could add a [DataGridViewImageColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.aspx) and populate it with images for each row.

Comment: ok, and can i hide only the ColumnHeader of the DataGridViewImageColumn?

Comment: You can't hide the column header entirely, but you can set the header text to an empty string and set column's sizing to AllCells. That'll basically size the column down to the dimensions of your biggest image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume ASP.Net. Here's an example with an image button. If you can provide more information, a better answer can be provided.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="some_image.jpg" /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```